# 'docker-compose' not found error when command was executed in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose

When i'm trying to execute `docker-compose up` as a shell build step command in Jenkins job, i got response `docker-compose: command not found`.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
Itself Jenkins is hosted on CentOS machine.

I've already added user  'jenkins' to 'sudoers' and to user groups: root, jenkins, docker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add your docker-compose executable to PATH envvar. Or use fully-specified path like this `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: indeed. Path /usr/local/bin wasn't specified for 'jenkins' user account on host. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This was the command that i was missing

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

I executed that and jenkins was fine

Comment: Experienced the same issue following a "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" on Ubuntu 18.04. Had the same issue for another tool, and this solution worked for me for both things.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install docker compose inside Jenkins env. Follow the below link to install https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by setting the environment PATH variable in Jenkins file like this:

```
  stage('test') {
            withEnv(["PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin"]){
                    sh "bash test.sh"
                }
        }
```